# How can i see what is inside of $0x27 and %ecx while using gdb debugger in linux?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, gdb, cpu-registers

cmp    $0x27,%ecx

I am currently looking for to see what is the value of  $0x27 and %ecx. What is the command I can see to find this.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?  Do you use a debugger?  Note that the value of `$0x27` is `0x27`.

Comment: Yea I am using a debugger in linux

Comment: What debugger?  Also, the tag you want is not [tag:vim-registers] but [tag:cpu-registers].

Comment: gdb @NateEldredge Thanks for edit

Comment: @www.com Then please refer to the gdb manual on how to display the contents of registers.  You should have this manual open whenever you use gdb.

Answer (score 1):

In gdb you can display the value of the `ecx` register with `p $ecx` (note gdb uses a `$` instead of `%` since it treats `$ecx` like one of its internal variables).  You can also use `info registers` to see the contents of all registers.

There's nothing "inside" `$0x27` - it's a literal immediate value, not a memory address.  It's like C `compare_into_flags(ecx, 0x27);`

Comment: I got $1 = 54 for %ecx and $2 = void for $0x2. Do you know what do they mean by any chance. My goal is for ecx to have the same value as $0x27?

Comment: Do `p 0x27`, without the $.